# get download dir from browser

Tags: r, browser, shiny

I have this `shiny`app where I want to download a file via a button. So I can do this by calling a `downloadHandler` like:

```
output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
      filename = "plot1.png",

   content = function(file) {
      plotPNG(func = function(){
            plot(some.Data)
         },
         filename = file,
         width = 3000,
         height = 2000,
         res = 300
      )
   }
)
```

Here the file is downloaded into the default download directory. What now if I want to download into another dir? In other words: Is there a way to determine the default download dir and to manipulate that?

Comment: you want to specify the directory to which the downloads are directed right?

Comment: You want the user to select a folder for download? If so; this sounds more like a browser setting.

Comment: Yes, I want to specify the dir to which the downloads are directed. I don't want the user to select a dir.

Comment: Are you downloading files to a shared folder by all the users?

Comment: @Chabo: Maybe, but not necessarily. Does this make a difference?

Comment: Definitely is browser setting, that's not about R or shiny.

Comment: OK thanks! And I assume there is no way to read that browser setting from whithin R, or is there?

Answer (score 0):

The downloadHandler() should be able to handle this problem. The filename argument is, "A string of the filename, ***including extension***, that the user's web browser should default to when downloading the file.." Therefore we can manipulate the default directory by defining the path in the filename.

```
server<-function(input,output){

output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(

# Sets filename the browser should default too
filename = function() {
  paste(PATH_TO_DIR,"plot1",".png/xls/etc.",sep="") 
}, # Closes Filename Function

# Creates Download file
content = function(file) {
  plotPNG(func = function(){
        plot(some.Data)
     },
     file = filename(),
     width = 3000,
     height = 2000,
     res = 300
  )
}

ui<-
downloadButton("downloadData", 'Download File')
)
```

This can be used in co-op with a download button, and the **name of the file and path can be dynamically generated** when the button is pushed by defining the path with variables. I think this may open a file browser, and I do not know if this is avoidable.

Also note that the file name, path, and content type will not appear to work in a local session (RStudio), they only work once deployed in the browser.